# Why does this jQuery code for making a div go to the top right or top left not work?

Tags: jquery, css, alignment

I'm affecting the CSS to make the absolute position change.

jQuery - this changes the absolute positioning to the top left and top right, eventually I want to do it for all corners but I'm starting with this

```
$('#topLeft').click(function() {
    $('#questionField').css('top', '0');
    $('#questionField').css('left', '0');
});

$('#topRight').click(function() {
    $('#questionField').css('top', '0');
    $('#questionField').css('right', '0');
});
```

HTML (aren't all my IDs and such correct?):

```
<body>
    <div id="questionField">    
        <form id="questions" action="process.html">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Hello World!</legend>
                <p>Firstly, which corner would you like this question box to be in?</p>
                <input type="radio" name="corner" id="topLeft" /><label for="topLeft"> Top Left</label><br />
                <input type="radio" name="corner" id="topRight" /><label for="topRight"> Top Right</label><br />
                <input type="radio" name="corner" id="bottomLeft" /><label for="bottomLeft"> Bottom Left</label><br />
                <input type="radio" name="corner" id="bottomRight" /><label for="bottomRight"> Bottom Right</label><br />

                <p>Now, some questions.</p>
                <label for="color">Favorite Color: </label><input type="text" id="color" /><br />
                <label for="animal">Favorite Animal: </label><input type="text" id="animal" /><br />
            <label for="paintBrush">Favorite Paint Brush: </label><input type="text" id="paintBrush" /><br />
                <label for="movie">Favorite Movie: </label><input type="text" id="movie" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS (it works if I affect this manually without jQuery, but jQuery doesn't seem to want to affect it!):

```
#questionField {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some subtleties that mean that your code, while correct, won't work...

1. Your `#questionField` element is currently 100% wide, so it is already touching the left side of the page (left: 0) and the right side of the page (right: 0). You need a width of less than 100% to see a change from left to right.
2. You should set position: absolute to use fixed co-ordinates for an element
3. Although these adjustments will work (See my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/TsEKH/)) Once you have clicked, you may get odd behaviour, for example, if I click top left, then top right, then top left, then top right, the box will stop moving as it gets confused when you have both left: 0 and right: 0 set - it cannot satisfy both rules and will choose to stick to the left. You need to revert the properties you previously set to make this work. Here is the full working code (assuming you have put a width on the element).

   ```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#topLeft').click(function() {
           $('#questionField').css({
               position: 'absolute',
               'top': '0px',
               'left': '0px',
               'right': 'auto'
           });
        });

        $('#topRight').click(function() {
           $('#questionField').css({
               position: 'absolute',
               'top': '0px',
               'right': '0px',
               'left': 'auto'
           });
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: This worked REALLY well. Thank you so much, exactly what I wanted.

Quick question if I may: 1. Does the .css({}); thing overwrite the CSS, or add to it? I'm assuming overwrite.

Comment: @DougSmith it only overwrites those CSS attributes that are being set. Other CSS attributes are left alone, which was causing your problem. That said: I don't want to toot my own horn, but you really should try adding and removing classes instead of individual styles, as it makes your code easier to tweak and manage as it grows more complex. You don't have to worry about overwriting unneeded CSS properties, because they disappear when the old class is removed.

Comment: I agree that in most cases adding and removing classes is easier to manage long term, so you may wish to adjust to that method. Of course, there are three sections in my answer which all contribute towards making this work and the JavaScript is just one of those.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of inline styles is getting in the way. After you click both buttons, jQuery sets inline CSS styles on the DIV and it looks like this: `<div id="questionField" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; ">` -- the "left:0" overrides the "right:0" and it sticks to the top left corner.

You need to either remove the old inline styles before you create new ones, or switch CSS classes instead. I would recommend the latter. Try this:

```
$('#topLeft').click(function() {
    $('#questionField').removeClass().addClass('topleft');
});

$('#topRight').click(function() {
    $('#questionField').removeClass().addClass('topright');
});
```

CSS:

```
#questionField {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
}
.topleft {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.topright {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/H8R6D/2/

Adding in the bottom corners is now trivial: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/H8R6D/3/

The only problem is that this will remove *all* classes on the DIV, including ones you don't want removed. If that's a problem, replace `.removeClass()` with `.removeClass('topright bottomright bottomleft')` (or something similar; it should list only the classes you *do* want removed).

Comment: I don't see any inline styles.

Comment: @TimJoyce `$('#questionField').css('left', '0');` sets inline styles on the DIV.

Comment: made that comment before you posted the code. Didn't make sense just reading it. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Also, don't forget to set the opposite positioning css back to default when the user changes their preference:

```
$('#questionField').css({
  'top': '0',
  'left': '0',
  'right': 'auto', // <--
  'bottom': 'auto' // <--
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to set `left` back to `auto` when you click for the top right and vice versa. If you just update the object CSS, you will have `left,top,right` all set at zero instead of just `top,right` like you want.

*UPDATE*

Added some code and CSS:

```
    #questionField
    {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 500px;
    }
    div.topright
    {
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    div.topleft
    {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    div.bottomright
    {
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    div.bottomleft
    {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#topLeft').click(function () {
            $('#questionField').removeClass('topright bottomright bottomleft').addClass('topleft');
        });
        $('#topRight').click(function () {
            $('#questionField').removeClass('topleft bottomright bottomleft').addClass('topright');
        });
        $('#bottomLeft').click(function () {
            $('#questionField').removeClass('topleft topright bottomright').addClass('bottomleft');
        });
        $('#bottomRight').click(function () {
            $('#questionField').removeClass('topleft topright bottomleft').addClass('bottomright');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

you should fill in a int not a string.

```
.css('top', 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to also put `.css('position', 'absolute')`  through jQuery if not defined in **CSS**

It will work, if its overwritten with another value just add !important like this

```
.css('position', 'absolute !important');
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't really said what's not working about it but just making sure you are calling the jquery after the elements have loaded.

```
$(function(){
$('#topLeft').click(function() {
    $('#questionField').css('top', '0');
    $('#questionField').css('left', '0');
});

$('#topRight').click(function() {
    $('#questionField').css('top', '0');
    $('#questionField').css('right', '0');
});
});
```

Also, I don't think in your css that you need to declare all corners of the element. Top & Left should be sufficient.

Comment: I eventually want to incorporate bottom as well, though. And by not working I meant when I click on the radio buttons nothing at all happens.

Answer (score -1):

It's because your div stretches the entire page. [Stick a background color on it and you'll see that like in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDchm/).

It actually is going to the top right or left... but since it's so huge it hits the other corner also.  By clicking on the different radio buttons you wind up specifying `right:0; left:0` makes your width 100%.  You'll need to adjust it so it doesn't fit the entire page when you move it's positioning.